# How to Check if input is float in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have function that loops through a structure array. It inputs elements inside that struct. My function is as follows:

```
void inputSubject(subject *subject ){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("\n[%d] ", i+1);
        printf("Enter Subject Code: ");
        scanf("%s", subject[i].subjectCode);
        printf("    Enter Units: ");
    //      scanf("%f", &subject[i].units);
    while(scanf("%f", &subject[i].units)!=1){
        printf("Invalid input. Re-enter units again: \n");
        scanf("%f", &subject[i].units);
     }



    printf("    Enter grade for subject: ");
    scanf("%f", &subject[i].grade);
        }

}
```

You may notice that there is a comment. After the commented code was supposed to check if the input Unit is a float. If it isn't then it would have to require the user to re-input the unit.

But it isn't working as I expected. If it sees that the input is not a float, it wouldn't prompt the user that what was inputted is not a float and it would not require the user to re-input an acceptable value. Instead, it makes an infinite loop of the `printf`

Same was supposed to be done for the grade.

Comment: Remember that `scanf` actually reads and *extracts* the characters it reads. So using two `scanf` calls would only work if the user actually entered two inputs. Also, the loop condition is wrong, it should loop while `scanf` *doesn't* return `1`. Lastly, a `while-do` loop would probably be better, with re-prompting inside the loop. Lastly, to be able to discard invalid input, consider reading the whole line, and using e.g. `sscanf` on that line instead.

Comment: you will tell your program.

Comment: You wish to check if it a float or int? Or it could be also char?

Comment: @t.elazari i only wish to check if it is a float sir, because in the later part of my program, I will have to make the average of all the collected floats

Comment: @AAngelo There are a number of questions about `scanf` leading to an infinite loop on invalid input. Did you check them out?

Comment: @CoolGuy I have searched in different forums sir. But I don't quite understand what they talk about since I'm very new to C programming

Comment: @AAngelo That's not a valid excuse. There are tons of posts out there and if you can't understand a single one of them, then its time to read your C textbook/tutorial once again. As for your problem, `scanf` fails, leaves the invalid input back into the input buffer and the next call to `scanf` sees the invalid input residing in the input buffer, fails, leaves it there, etc etc. This is why you have an infinite loop

Comment: The solution would be to remove the invalid stuff from the input stream. Create a function called `flush_stdin`: `void flush_stdin() { int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); }` and call it from your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard input is buffered. Anything that is given as input is first placed in a buffer from where the functions take them.

For example, when you give `3.14` as input, it is first placed in the buffer from where the `scanf("%f")` reads it.

When you give a non-float value, the `scanf()` didn't find the `%f` it expected. So it leaves the input in the input buffer itself and the next statement of the program is executed which happens to be another `scanf()` expecting `%f`. The input which was not consumed by the previous `scanf()` is still there in the input buffer and this is what the next `scanf()` uses. Again, the value is left unconsumed.

What you got to do is to somehow consume the non-float value in the input buffer after each failed read.

You could do something like

```
int ch;
while( (ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!=EOF );
```

to consume from the input buffer till a newline. The newline would've been given when the user presses the Enter key.

`scanf()` returns the number of variables to which values were successfully assigned. This value should be `1` in this case for a successful read.

```
char ch;
while(scanf("%f", &subject[i].units)!=1){
    printf("Invalid input. Re-enter units again: \n");
    while( (ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!=EOF );
}
```

You can do away with the second `scanf()`.

Answer (score -2):

include math.h header file and do like this if you want an integer value for units

```
scanf("%f",&a);
    while(a-floor(a)!=0){
            printf("please enter a integer value");
            scanf("%f",&a);
    }
```